# htaccess only in root folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I was looking for an answer, but didn't find it. I have .htaccess in root file which redirect /loremipsum/ to index.php?url=loremipsum, but, it also wants to work in subdirectories. I have a lot of them, so putting .htaccess file in everyone would be painful. Is there any way to make it working only in root folder?

Comment: What's the rules that you are using?

Comment: `Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks`
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?url=$1 [L]`

Comment: maybe change `index.php` to `/index.php`? Not sure what you mean by working in subdirectories.

Comment: I mean that if i go to myaddres.com which is the domain parked on the same server i can't access even index.php because .htaccess is in root folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add this rules it will only work on files and folders that didnt exist

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your redirect rule work only in root dir use this **negative lokahead** based code:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(?!/.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```